# How to bind to already binded object?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, data-binding, telerik, bind

In xaml, i have Dependency Property for image (which works like cacher). Now, i want to bind PanAndZoomImage to the same image, but it cant use DP, because it is not inherited from Image.

Can i bind like?

```
                <Image 
                    x:Name="BigImage" 
                    wpExtensions:ImageProperties.LazyLink="{Binding ProductItem.Image}" />

                     <slideView:PanAndZoomImage 
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            ZoomMode="Free"
                            Source="{Binding BigImage}" // How to bind here to image?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a element name binding:

```
 <slideView:PanAndZoomImage 
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        ZoomMode="Free"
                        Source="{Binding Source,ElementName=BigImage}"
```

Comment: Actually, i made it in codebehind, but using ElementName is more native and elegant way.